# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable when executing an " if " conditional

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

When I run the code below in python 3 and input the letter 'a', I get the error: " 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" for the last line of the code. On the other hand, when I try similar codes in the shell, it executes the "if" conditional without a problem. I would be glad if I got some help. :)

```
letters_guessed = []
letters_guessed = letters_guessed.append(str.lower(str(input('Please guess a letter (you can only guess one letter at a time): '))))
            if letters_guessed[-1].isalpha() == True:
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code here:

```
letters_guessed = letters_guessed.append(str.lower(str(input('Please guess a letter (you can only guess one letter at a time): '))))
```

Is wrong. Change it to:

```
letters_guessed.append(str.lower(str(input('Please guess a letter (you can only guess one letter at a time): '))))
```

Comment: Your solution seems correct to me. Want to add details about what exactly is wrong? That may help more than a bland "use this instead".

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error, we must remove the declaration of the `letters_guessed` variable and leave `letters_guessed.append()` on its own line.

```
letters_guessed = []
letters_guessed.append(str.lower(str(input('Please guess a letter (you can only guess one letter at a time): '))))
if letters_guessed[-1].isalpha() == True:
    ...
```